# How does mouseevents works?

Tags: javascript

You could setup special mouse events using Javascript that fires when the pointer is enter or hovering over a specific HTML element (i.e: object.addEventListener("mouseover", theScript); ). But how does it work?

Is it like a classic collison detection? When the mouse pointer X and Y coordinates is inside the boundaries of the element it reports to all listeners of the event.

This is maybe something that is browser specific but I guess there is similiar approaches between the browsers(?).

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

The browser has to know where to put all the elements it draws, so when the OS tells it that the mouse has moved, it can do simple `left < X < right` and `top < Y < bottom` checks with the *from position* and the *to position* to see if the mouse has entered (or exited) the element. It can then deal with all the `:hover`, `mouseover`, etc.

The OS will do a similar thing with the actual hardware messages and open windows.

The exact code will of course vary between browsers and OSs, but the basic algorithm is very simple.